# Bibliography by section in Lyx using memoir

Tags: lyx, memoir

I am using Lyx 2.2.1 and the memoir style. I want the bibliography to be show at the end of each Chapter --just the citations of that chapter-- and added at the TOC.
I have inserted a bib file at the end of the document. Then, in Lyx, click at Document -> Configuration -> Bibliography and click on "Bibliography by sections". This is clearly not the option (sections instead of Chapters) but nevertheless the bibliography do not show up.
I am using Natbib (Year Author) as the default presentation of the bibliography. Nevertheless, the bibliography do not show at each Chapter, but at the end of the document.
If I put the bib file in each Chapter, then the document clashes.
I want to know:

1. the bib file should be only one time at the end, or in each chapter?
2. which is the package that should be included in the preamble to get the bibliography shown in each chapter?
3. Which are the commands to be set in order to make the bibliography appear in each chapter?

Thanks
Leandro

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be helpful to show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: For my thesis in LyX I did a separate bibliography at the end of each chapter. You might be able to adapt it to your needs.  See https://github.com/scottkosty/lyx-princeton-diss

Comment: Hi, @scottkosky for the file. I have download the Lyx file. I try to compile it but find the following message: Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.


Package bibtopic Warning: Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):
(bibtopic)                princeton-diss.1
(bibtopic)                princeton-diss.2
(bibtopic)                princeton-diss.3
(bibtopic)                and after that rerun LaTeX. I have used either biber and biblatex, but found no solution. I do not understand how to compile Bibtex on Lyx. Do you have any clue?